# How to build Opengl with sublime3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, opengl, sublimetext3

Just like the title. I have tried many ways but it doesn't work. Here are what I wrote and the error message.

```
***
    {
        "cmd": ["gcc -o $file_name $file_base_name -lGL -lGLU -lglut"],
        "working_dir": "${project_path}",
        "selector": ["source.c"],
        "shell": true,
        "variants": 
        [{
            "name": "Run",
            "cmd": ["$file_path/$file_base_name"]
        }]
    }***
```

error message:

> *****/bin/bash: ./gl: No such file or directory*****

Comment: What does "building OpenGL" even mean?

Comment: just like run a program in IDE

Comment: Well. You are certainly not building OpenGL. Whatever you try to build here depends on OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a wrong gcc command:

```
gcc -o $file_name $file_base_name -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

should probably be

```
gcc -o $file_base_name $file_name -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

The argument directly after the -o is the destination file, and you seem to use $file_base_name to run it.

Not sure if that is the only error though, as I am not familiar with sublime3.